# Apache Spark: Exponential Moving Average

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am writing an application in Spark/Scala in which I need to calculate the exponential moving average of a column.

```
EMA_t = (price_t * 0.4) + (EMA_t-1 * 0.6)
```

The problem I am facing is that I need the previously calculated value (EMA_t-1) of the same column. Via mySQL this would be possible by using MODEL or by creating an EMA column which you can then update row per row, but I've tried this and neither work with the Spark SQL or Hive Context... Is there any way I can access this EMA_t-1?

My data looks like this :

```
timestamp price    
15:31 132.3 
15:32 132.48 
15:33 132.76 
15:34 132.66
15:35 132.71 
15:36 132.52
15:37 132.63
15:38 132.575
15:39 132.57
```

So I would need to add a new column where my first value is just the price of the first row and then I would need to use the previous value: EMA_t = (price_t * 0.4) + (EMA_t-1 * 0.6) to calculate the following rows in that column.
My EMA column would have to be:

```
EMA
132.3
132.372
132.5272
132.58032
132.632192
132.5873152
132.6043891
132.5926335
132.5835801
```

I am currently trying to do it using Spark SQL and Hive but if it is possible to do it in another way, this would be just as welcome! I was also wondering how I could do this with Spark Streaming. My data is in a dataframe and I am using Spark 1.4.1.

Thanks a lot for any help provided!

Comment: I don't think your use case is well suited for a big data environment since its power is to process data in parallel and your use case doesn't allow this...how many records do you have?

Comment: @mark91 I have about 100 000 rows per dataset and about 100 datasets I need to analyze. The reason I need to calculate this is that I need this as input to calculate a feature. I would need to use these features to train a model with random forest. My model has to predict whether the price will go up or down based on the values of several features. I also would need to make this real-time in the future.

Comment: Then up to me the best option is to distribute the data such as each dataset is in a partition (and each partition contains a dataset) and then you process independently each partition..

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> The problem I am facing is that I need the previously calculated value (EMA_t-1) of the same column

I think you need two functions: Window and Lag. (I also make null value to zero for convenience when calculating EMA)

```
my_window = Window.orderBy("timestamp")

df.withColumn("price_lag_1",when(lag(col("price"),1).over(my_window).isNull,lit(0)).otherwise(lag(col("price"),1).over(my_window)))
```

I am new to Spark Scala also, and am trying to see if I can define an UDF to do the exponential average. But for now an obvious walk around would be manually adding up all lag column ( 0.4 * lag0 + 0.4*0.6*lag1 + 0.4 * 0.6^2*lag2 ...) Something like this

```
df.withColumn("ema_price", 
price * lit(0.4) * Math.pow(0.6,0) + 
lag(col("price"),1).over(my_window) * 0.4 * Math.pow(0.6,1) +
lag(col("price"),2).over(my_window) * 0.4 * Math.pow(0.6,2)  + .... )
```

I ignored the when.otherwise to make it more clear. And this method works for me now..

**----Update----**

```
def emaFunc (y: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, group: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, order: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, beta: Double, lookBack: Int) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
  val ema_window = Window.partitionBy(group).orderBy(order)
  var i = 1
  var result = y
  while (i < lookBack){
    result =  result + lit(1) * ( when(lag(y,i).over(ema_window).isNull,lit(0)).otherwise(lag(y,i).over(ema_window)) * beta * Math.pow((1-beta),i) 
    - when(lag(y,i).over(ema_window).isNull,lit(0)).otherwise(y * beta * Math.pow((1-beta),i))   )
    i = i + 1
  }
  return result }
```

By using this fuction you should be able to get EMA of price like..

```
df.withColumn("one",lit(1))
  .withColumn("ema_price", emaFunc('price,'one,'timestamp,0.1,10)
```

This will look back 10 days and calculate estimate EMA with beta=0.1. Column "one" is just a place holder since you don't have grouping column.

Comment: can you let me know how the calculation of beta as 0.1 is been calculated. I am trying the above code and finding the value of EMA 10. I am not getting proper values so I think I need to change beta value so can you help me how beta 0.1 is calculated?

Comment: Beta is like a decay factor. It is the parameter. you set the beta depend on how much you care about today, vs. how much you care about the history. @M

Comment: What if I will not use  this beta parameter bcoz I am not getting exactly what I want ?

Comment: @MaheshGupta I guess this formula requires you set beta(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average), or maybe you could talk more about what exactly you want?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this with Spark Window Functions, which were introduced in 1.4: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(col("timestamp"))
df.select("*", lag("price").over(w).alias("ema"))

This would select the last price for you so you can do your calculations on it